# Best way to create a user with no password

Tags: linux, password, useradd, login, nobody

What is the good way to create a user with no password?
By no password, I mean an account, that would be usable only by the root account using the su/sudo commands (like the "nobody" user used by Apache or Nginx).

I've read that putting a * in the password field of the /etc/shadow file works but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it with the useradd command.

I thought of doing:

```
useradd my_new_user -s /sbin/nologin -p '*'
```

but I'm not sure the useradd command can be used this way. I haven't found any reference about it.

Comment: "no password" means "don't have password" or "blank password"?

Answer (score 5):

This works the way you described (of course you can specify whichever shell you'd like in place of `/bin/bash`):

```
root# useradd temp_test1 -s /bin/bash -p '*'
root# su temp_test1
temp_test1#
```

After executing the above `useradd` command, the following entry is in my `/etc/shadow` file:

```
temp_test1:*:15842:0:99999:7:::
```

When using *John Smith Optional*'s answer, the following will work:

```
root# useradd temp_test2 -s /sbin/nologin
root# su -s /bin/bash temp_test2
temp_test2#
```

**EDIT:**  I'd like to point out that the difference is that you cannot `su` into an account which has the shell specified as `/sbin/nologin` unless you specify a usable shell when issuing the `su` command:

```
root# useradd temp_test3 -s /sbin/nologin
root# su temp_test3
This account is currently not available.
root#
```

(Tested in CentOS 6.4 -- should work in a variety of distros).

Answer (score 2):

```
useradd my_new_user -s /sbin/nologin
```

If a password is not specified, one is not created/account disabled.

Comment: You can't `su` into a `nologin` account without specifying a shell with the `su` command.

Comment: Sure you can, you just need to specify a different shell: `su -s /bin/bash my_new_user`